# What's the difference between `until` and `until do` loops in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops

```
c = 5
until c == 0 do
  print c
  c -= 1
end
```

/break

```
c = 5
until c == 0 
  print c
  c -= 1
end
```

What's the difference?
Both of them display `54321` as output.

Comment: same. Its just optional to add `do`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do` is optional. It indicates the beginning of the block of code to be repeatedly executed.

In your example it makes no difference. However if you try re-writing the code in one line, you can see why its needed:

```
c = 5
until c == 0 do print c; c -= 1 end
# 54321 => nil
```

Now try this without `do`:

```
c = 5
until c == 0 print c; c -= 1 end
# SyntaxError: (irb):115: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do_cond or ';' or '\n'
```

As you can see there is no clear beginning for block, Ruby will throw a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: The only thing not mentioned in this answer is that we (Rubyists) mostly use iterators, that look like `something.each do ... end`, so using `do` here makes the loop look much like another iterator.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no difference. It is like the `while [condition] [block] end` vs `while [condition] do [block] end` or `if [condition] [block] end` vs `if [condition] then [block] end`.

In Ruby, often there are tons of ways of doing the same thing - the important is to be consistent, either way.

Comment: Do-while and while loops are different. One is exit-controlled, the other is entry-controlled.

Comment: @therewillbecoffee I meant `while [condition] do [exp] end`. Surely `do [exp] while [condition]` works differently. Will make it clear, though :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between `until` and `until do`. `Do` is optional and both will show same output. If want to get some more idea about this [while and while do](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_While_and_Until_Loops)